# CoinBase API not returning product ticker data

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I am trying to get the product ticker from CoinBase API  https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getproductticker using two different functions. The first one is the following:

```
def connect_to_coinbase_ticker(product_id: str):

    url = f"https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/products/{product_id}/ticker"

    headers = {"accept": "application/json"}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
```

But I am getting this response message : `{"message": "NotFound"}`

By looking at the above link I also tried to use the function it is provided there to get these data:

```
def connect_to_coinbase_ticker(product_id: str):

    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.exchange.coinbase.com")
    payload = ''
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    conn.request("GET", f"/products/{product_id}/ticker", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

But I keep getting an error message: `{"message":"User-Agent header is required."}`

So my question is how can I modify one of the above functions so I do not get these messages and get the product ticker data I request.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure first that your `pruduct_id` is correct. I've used "btc-usd" and it works fine (don't forget the dash).
As for the second function that requires the user-agent, you can add it like this:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 8172.45.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.64 Safari/537.36'}
```

or whatever user-agent string that you want. You can google "whats my user agent string" to find out what is your actual user agent and use it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the ```'User-Agent'``` header and now the response message is just ```{"message":"NotFound"}``` and I am just trying to get  a simple BTCUSD ticker as ```product_id```

Comment: I've edited my answer.